# How to prevent Gradle job running in background on TFS agent

Tags: selenium, gradle, azure-devops, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have configured a Windows 7 VM as an agent to my TFS2015 setup.

I have created a Gradle (invoking the gradlew.bat) job to run my selenium scripts from the TFS build definition as

```
gradlew.bat clean test aggregate
```

This works fine (I can see IE being invoked) when I run it MANUALLY from the VM directly, BUT when the same is triggered as a job, it runs only in the background. Here are my observations:

1. The processes - Java, iexplorer, IEDriver.exe are all getting invoked in the Process manager.
2. When I kill iexplorer process, I can see the UnreachableBrowserException on the TFS console and the next test case runs.
3. The job with 2 test cases (approx 3-4 mins) fail after running for 10 mins and I see the error logs in TFS console
4. The scripts ran on UI the very first time I set this up but has never run after that.

I am using Gradle 3.0 and have disabled the Gradle Daemon by adding org.gradle.daemon=false in gradle.properties. This has been bugging me for a couple of days so badly.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Is your build agent running interactive or as a service?

Comment: Its running as a Service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your tests to interact with the desktop they will need to be running interactively on a machine that is logged on and not locked (no screensaver active).

See: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/v2-windows#interactive

You can configure the machine to start-up automatically and authenticate on start-up, disable the scren locking policy and screensavers and add the run.cmd to the windows start-up section in the star-menu.

See: http://donovanbrown.com/post/2015/08/28/auto-start-build-agent-in-interactive-mode

- Press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the Run dialog
- Type in the following and press enter: 
  `control userpasswords2`
- Uncheck the box for User must enter a user name and password to use this computer.
- Click the <kbd>Apply</kbd> button
- You will be prompted by an Automatically sign in dialog
- Enter the password for the user
- Click <kbd>OK</kbd>
- Click <kbd>OK</kbd> on the Users Accounts dialog

And

- Right-click the desktop
- Select New / Shortcut
- Enter `cmd`
- Click <kbd>Next</kbd>
- Change the name to Start Agent
- Click <kbd>Finish</kbd>
- Right-click on the new shortcut
- Select <kbd>Properties</kbd>
- Append `/c {pathTo\run.cmd}` to the target
- If you installed your agent to C:\Agent, your target should look like this: `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c c:\agent\agent\run.cmd`
- Click <kbd>OK</kbd>

*Note:* updated for the 2.0 build agent, which is started using `run.cmd` instead of `vsoagent.exe`

- Press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the Run dialog
- Type in the following 
  `shell:startup`
- Click <kbd>OK</kbd>
- This will open the Startup folder in Windows Explorer.
- Drag and drop the shortcut to this folder

Comment: Excellent. Works like a charm.